# Retrieve Fields from Foreign key table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have these two tables and I want to get some values from the second table for two foreign key in the first table.

**Team** table:

```
ID   | Name          | No_Players | Country  | F_Year | Team_Logo
-----+---------------+------------+----------+--------+----------------------
1    | Real Madrid   |  22        | Spain    | 1940   | Http://Xyz.jpg  
2    | Arsenal       |  22        | England  | 1950   | Http://XXYYZZ.jpg  
3    | FCB.Barcelona |  22        | Spain    | 1960   | Http://YYZZz.jpg  
4    | Bayern Meunekh|  22        | Germany  | 1940   | Http://GGG.jpg
```

**Matches** table:

```
ID | Date        |First_Team     | Second_Team | M_Country |M_City   | M_Period | Result
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |15-02-2016   | Real Madrid   | Arsenal     | Spain     |  Madrid | 120      | 1-1
2  |19-03-2016   | FCB.Barecolna | Madrid      | Spain     |  Madrid | 90       | 4-5
```

And I want to Get the Team_Logo For each team in the matches table in the json form in this PHP Script. I've tried to get teams logo but unfortunately the query is invalid.

If anyone can help me please?

```
<?php
require ('config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$query = "select * from matches,team where matches.first_team=team.Name OR matches.second_team=team.Name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$rows = array();
echo mysqli_error($conn);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: You need to use joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    matches.*,
    t1.Team_Logo AS logo1,
    t2.Team_Logo AS logo2
FROM matches
JOIN team AS t1
    ON t1.Name = matches.First_Team
JOIN team As t2
    ON t2.Name = matches.Second_Team
```

Also note that you should not select * because the Id columns from the team tables will override the Id column of the matches table.
That's why you should include only columns you like to select.

Comment: This is the Correct query

Answer (score 1):

You should try this query :

```
$query="select m.*,t.* from matches as m INNER JOIN on team as t1 ON m.First_Team=t1.Name JOIN team As t2
ON m.Second_Team=t2.Name";
```

Comment: this gives me an Error

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on team as t where matches.first_team=team.Name OR matches.second_team=team.Name' at line 1

Comment: You *"guess they should try this"*? Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use relational database structure.

add primary key for both table

add reference key of first table's primary key in second table as foreign key.

and refer bellow query.

```
sql="SELECT * FROM Matches as m JOIN Team as t ON t.ID = m.t_id where t.id=1 OR t.id=2
```

Comment: Also this gives me an Error : 

Unknown column 'm.t.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: had you add 't_id' in match table as foreign key, refer from team table ?